# Alignment requirement for variables protected using gcc's __sync_xxx functions on ARM

Tags: c, gcc, atomic

My understanding of atomic operations on any HW platform is that it requires aligned memory addresses to provided atomic operations. On x86 an entire cache line is locked to implement CAS making the alignment requirement a cache line. On the ARM that I'm using the ERG is set to 4 implying a 64 byte Exclusive reservation granule. However in the code base that we have, I have found `__sync_fetch_and_add()` calls where the variable being operated on has no alignment requirements in its declaration.

Does anyone have experience with this on ARM? Should I align my atomic variables to the ERG boundary before using the `__sync` functions? The GCC documentation makes no mention of alignment.

Comment: x86 does *not* require alignment for `lock`ed RMW operations.

Comment: The `__sync_XXX` builtins are legacies and deprecated. Use `stdatomic.h`! This will also solve your alignment problems (unless you use broken code). It is also not clear why you have an alignement problem. If the code is compiled properly and does not invoke undefined behaviour, all data will be aligned correctly for your platform. Said that: XY-problem, your code most likely relies on undefined behaviour - very bad idea.

Comment: @EOF thanks for the comment. I read that the RMW instructions can monitor a cache line and fail an RMW if the cache line has been dirtied since being read. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this means that the atomic implementations will have to retry the transaction. Does non aligned access just mean that performance is reduced given that the operation will be retried ?

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for the suggestion but I'm running on a vendor supplied toolchain which sees to be setup with c99 rules and I believe the atomics are c11 only.

Comment: @KartikAiyer: Yes, but the XY problem is still most likely. I've seen enough such code. As you are using gcc: there is little to none vendor-specific about that. Just install a more recent version of gcc. If youi pay the vendor: you pay for nothing.

Comment: @KartikAiyer An x86 *could* have some extra cache logic to only make a cacheline-straddling atomic operation if it has both cachelines exclusively, but there might be deadlock concerns. AFAIK, actual x86 implementations fall back to bus locking.

Comment: As a sidenote: what do you mean with "protected by …"? These functions don't protect anything.